# How to create viewonly field in SqlAlchemy and GeoAlchemy2?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, geoalchemy

I am trying to dynamically populate a field using SqlAlchemy 0.8.4 and GeoAlchemy2 0.2.2. The goal is to assign a District to the Facility based on the facility's position when it is read from the database. The code looks like this:

```
class District(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'districts'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    geom = Column('geog', Geometry(geometry_type='POLYGON'), nullable=False)

class Facility(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'facilities'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    pos = Column('geog', Geometry(geometry_type='POINT'), nullable=True)
    district = relationship(District,
                            viewonly=True,
                            primaryjoin="District.geom.ST_Contains(Facility.pos)",
                            foreign_keys=[District.id])
```

But this gives me the following error:

> ArgumentError: Could not locate any relevant foreign key columns for
>   primary join condition 'ST_Contains(districts.geog, facilities.geog)'
>   on relationship Facility.district.   Ensure that referencing columns
>   are associated with a ForeignKey or ForeignKeyConstraint, or are
>   annotated in the join condition with the foreign() annotation

I would really like to avoid having foreignkey relation between these classes since the districts are constantly changing, but would like to get a facility with a district set without querying the database again.

How should I solve this?

Comment: Hi, I'm trying to do something similar, did you ever figure this out?